# How do you include files in C++ from the /Library/Framework folder in MAC

Tags: c++, macos, compilation, include, sdl

I am trying to use SDL. I have a folder in `/Library/Frameworks` called `SDL2.framework`. I want to include the file `SDL.h` in my project. How do I do this? My code looks like:

```
// Example program:
// Using SDL2 to create an application window

#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    SDL_Window *window;                    // Declare a pointer
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);              // Initialize SDL2
    // Create an application window with the following settings:
    window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "An SDL2 window",                  // window title
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,           // initial x position
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,           // initial y position
        640,                               // width, in pixels
        480,                               // height, in pixels
        SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL                  // flags - see below
    );
    // Check that the window was successfully made
    if (window == NULL) {
        // In the event that the window could not be made...
        printf("Could not create window: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }
    // The window is open: enter program loop (see SDL_PollEvent)
    SDL_Delay(3000);  // Pause execution for 3000 milliseconds, for example
    // Close and destroy the window
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    // Clean up
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Aarons-MacBook-Air:SDL aaron$ g++ main.cpp
main.cpp:4:10: fatal error: 'SDL.h' file not found
#include <SDL.h>
          ^ 1 error generated.
```

How do I properly include the SDL file? It is inside `SDL2.framework`, `headers`, `SDL.h`...

Comment: did you add the framework to the project?

Comment: I am using VIM. Nothing to add to it. The entire code base is represented above. I am trying not to use any kind of XCODE or other building tool. Just trying to build using g++ in the command line. @Grady Player

Comment: @GradyPlayer Trying to add you to this.

Comment: then you need to pass a flag to the compiler to tell it which frameworks to use, alternately the include and lib paths.

Comment: @GradyPlayer Can you show me how?

Comment: I am working on this now @aaron... there doesn't appear to be a shipping version of sdl with mac os x... so it wont be a framework (in the os x context... unless it is packaged that way specifically).

Comment: @GradyPlayer http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-2.0.1.dmg That is the direct link to the SDL package I used. I don't know if that helps.

Comment: @GradyPlayer how to pass a flag to compiler to use some framework?

Comment: @mbaros `-framework FrameworkName`

Comment: @GradyPlayer thank you. It worked...!!!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you will want to make a build script for this obviously, but the important parts are:

`-I/usr/local/include` or wherever your headers get installed.

I used home brew:

`brew install sdl2`

which puts the libraries in `/usr/local/Cellar/`

so if you need to specify the lib path you will also add:

`-L/usr/local/lib -lSDL2`

I also changed your include line to `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>`

Comment: My Make file now looks like thus -- all:
 g++ main.cpp -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lSDL2

Answer (score 3):

Your header files is under the Headers folder, so in order to include this properly:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers/
```

But I recommend Installing with homebrew:

```
brew install sdl2
```

Homebrew will install SDL2 libSDL2.a file under /usr/local/lib and /usr/local/include, so you will just need to include this Library path using the -L for library and -I flag to add search in /usr/local/include dir:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ main.cpp -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lSDL2 -o programfile
```

And include:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
```